# Java - Byte[] to byte[]

Tags: java, byte, arrays

There is Vector and DataOutputStream. I need to write bytes from Vector (toArray returns Byte[]) to the stream, but it understands byte[] only. How to convert Byte[] to byte[] ?

Comment: @Nick is joking. You may note that he is calling `toLowerCase()` on the string `"Byte[]"`. Yeah, I know, by explaining it, I ruined the joke.

Comment: @Oded explanations of jokes are funny in themselves :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use the [toPrimitive](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Byte%5B%5D%29) method in the [Apache Commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library  [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html) class?

Answer (score 9):

```
byte[] toPrimitives(Byte[] oBytes)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[oBytes.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < oBytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = oBytes[i];
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Inverse:

```
// byte[] to Byte[]
Byte[] toObjects(byte[] bytesPrim) {
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[bytesPrim.length];

    int i = 0;
    for (byte b : bytesPrim) bytes[i++] = b; // Autoboxing

    return bytes;
}
```

freeone3000 contributed in this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

A Vector<Byte> is about as inefficient structure as you could use to store bytes. I would serious consider using something more efficient line ByteArrayOutputStream which has a toByteArray() method. i.e. don't just convert the Vector but remove it from the code.

Comment: My only contention with this is that any writes to the ByteArrayOutputStream now require `try{}catch(){}` for no real reason other than that it inherits from OutputStream.

Comment: I'd say this is an interesting comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: @TomasVinter For me, sometimes the best answer is don't do that, do this instead.  i.e. you are just making a bad idea worse. ;)