# How to convert byte[] to Byte[] and the other way around?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, boxing

How to convert `byte[]` to `Byte[]` and also `Byte[]` to `byte[]`, in the case of not using any 3rd party library?

Is there a way to do it fast just using the standard library?

Comment: 10 questions, ONE accepted? No good

Comment: Why do you need/have a `Byte[]`? Doesn't seem like a good idea... either use `byte[]` or `List<Byte>`.

Comment: Might be useful if the values can be null, though probably not very efficient (ie. wastes any space-benefit of storing bytes, because of all the object references)?

Comment: But you can't convert a `Byte[]` to a `byte[]` if you have null references...

Comment: @BalusC ok, 1 of 7. Haven't improved a lot!

Comment: @Dunes One reason to have Byte[] is that it becomes an intermediate form of trying to call toArray on a List<Byte>. In this case, writing your own loop seems to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`Byte` class is a *wrapper* for the primitive `byte`. This should do the work:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
Byte[] byteObjects = new Byte[bytes.length];

int i=0;    
// Associating Byte array values with bytes. (byte[] to Byte[])
for(byte b: bytes)
   byteObjects[i++] = b;  // Autoboxing.

....

int j=0;
// Unboxing Byte values. (Byte[] to byte[])
for(Byte b: byteObjects)
    bytes[j++] = b.byteValue();
```

Comment: Would definitely recommend `Byte.valueOf(b)` over `new Byte(b)`. I would be surprised if the Byte class didn't cache every single value for a byte.

Comment: I believe that it might be better to use `Byte.valueOf(byte)`. JavaDocs say that this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor `Byte(byte)`, as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance since all byte values are cached.

Comment: With autoboxing, you can simply do `byteObjects[i++] = b;`

Comment: I'd use `new Byte[bytes.length];` instead of `new Byte[10];` to keep it sensible.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. The i++ and j++ in the for-each loop don't do anything useful. You need to use the basic for-loop: for (int i=0; i<bytes.length;i++) { byteObjects[i] = b[i]; }. Same goes for unboxing.

Comment: @user504342 have you ever debugged my code? with my code i and j goes from 0 to 10 and handles the job.

Comment: @Juvanis aha, I see that you use two "counters" in the for-loop: one to iterate over the primitive byte array and/or Byte object array, and another one for incrementing the index of the primitive byte array and/or Byte object array. To me, this is bad practice. If this code is maintained by others, and someone would modify the counter "i" from 0 to another value, or would change the i++ into ++i, the indexes no longer match. I am not advocating anyone should modify the code in the first place, but it's a common pitfall for beginners. My suggestion keeps the indexes of both arrays in sync.

Answer (score 91):

byte[] to Byte[] :

```
byte[] bytes = ...;
Byte[] byteObject = ArrayUtils.toObject(bytes);
```

Byte[] to byte[] :

```
Byte[] byteObject = new Byte[0];
byte[] bytes = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(byteObject);
```

Note: ArrayUtils are not a part of Java, but Apache lib

Comment: Why this is not the best answer? Any performace reason or just answered later?

Comment: Because the ArrayUtils are not a part of Java, but Apache lib.

Comment: I agree with @mvorisek, this should be considered the best answer. Just add org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils

Comment: Unfortunately, `ArrayUtils` is not part of standard Java packages.

Comment: apache commons lang is a great package that should be part of any java project.

Comment: The question explicitly asks for a non third party library.

Answer (score 22):

Java 8 solution:

```
Byte[] toObjects(byte[] bytesPrim) {
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[bytesPrim.length];
    Arrays.setAll(bytes, n -> bytesPrim[n]);
    return bytes;
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't do this to convert from `Byte[]` to `byte[]`.  `Arrays` has `setAll` for `double[]`, `int[]`, and `long[]`, but not for other primitive types.

Comment: Best answer for me. Simple code and no third-party library.

Answer (score 16):

You could use the toPrimitive method in the Apache Commons lang library ArrayUtils class,
As suggested here - [Java - Byte[] to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430841/java-byte-to-byte)

Comment: This is actually the best answer, at least for anyone for whom adding a dependency to commons-lang isn't an issue.

Answer (score 8):

```
byte[] toPrimitives(Byte[] oBytes)
{

    byte[] bytes = new byte[oBytes.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < oBytes.length; i++){
        bytes[i] = oBytes[i];
    }
    return bytes;

}
```

Inverse:

```
//byte[] to Byte[]
Byte[] toObjects(byte[] bytesPrim) {

    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[bytesPrim.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (byte b : bytesPrim) bytes[i++] = b; //Autoboxing
    return bytes;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

From byte[] to Byte[]:

```
    byte[] b = new byte[]{1,2};
    Byte[] B = new Byte[b.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
        B[i] = Byte.valueOf(b[i]);
    }
```

From Byte[] to byte[] (using our previously-defined `B`):

```
    byte[] b2 = new byte[B.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++)
    {
        b2[i] = B[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If someone preferes Stream API over ordinary loops.

```
private Byte[] toObjects(byte[] bytes) {
    return IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> bytes[i])
            .toArray(Byte[]::new);
}
```

Comment: and the other way round?

Comment: I think you can't get byte[] from Stream. Stream api has mapToInt(), mapToDouble() and mapToLong() methods but not mapToByte().

Answer (score 0):

Step back.  Look at the bigger picture.  You're stuck converting byte[] to Byte[] or vice versa because of Java's strict type casing with something like this

> List< Byte>
> or
> List<Byte[]>

Now you have byte[] and Byte[] and have to convert.  This will help.

Keep all your byte[]s in a list like this:  List<byte[]> instead of List< Byte> or List<Byte[]>. (byte is a primitive, byte[] is an object)

As you acquire bytes do this (networking socket example):

```
ArrayList<byte[]> compiledMessage = new ArrayList<byte[]>;
...
compiledMessage.add(packet.getData());
```

Then, when you want to put all your bytes in a single message, do this:

```
byte[] fromListOfNotByteArray (List<byte[]> list) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(list);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

That way, you can keep all your parts in List<byte[]> and your whole in byte[] without a bunch of crazy copy tasks in for loops with little baby byte[]s everywhere.  ;)

Now you know -- teach others.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8:

```
byte[] bytes = new bytes[byteObject.length];
IntStream.range(0, byteObject.length).forEach(x -> bytes [x] = byteObject[x]);
```