# Convert List<Byte> to string

Tags: java, list, arraylist, byte

I have the following code:

```
List<String> decryptedPasswordInPairs = new ArrayList<String>();
String A5 = "A5";
for (String oddPair : oddPairsInEncryptedPassword) {
    List<Byte> sample = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < oddPair.length(); i++) {
        byte x = (byte) (oddPair.charAt(i) ^ A5.charAt(i % A5.length()));
        sample.add(x);
    }
    String result = sample.toString();
    decryptedPasswordInPairs.add(result);
}
```

In this code, `result` is displayed as `[0,7]` instead of `07` when I debug the program to check the value of `result`.

Is there a way to convert this `List` of `Byte`s to a `String` without having any problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this solution, I collect the characters in a StringBuilder and convert to a String at the end:

```
List<String> decryptedPasswordInPairs = new ArrayList<String>();
    String A5 = "A5";

    List<String> oddPairsInEncryptedPassword = new LinkedList<String>();
    oddPairsInEncryptedPassword.add("A2");

    for (String oddPair : oddPairsInEncryptedPassword) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < oddPair.length(); i++) {
            byte x = (byte) (oddPair.charAt(i) ^ A5.charAt(i % A5.length()));
            sb.append(""+x);
        }

        String result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
        decryptedPasswordInPairs.add(result);
    }
```

Comment: Good approach, thank you. But it does not show the output as 07.

Comment: What String input are you trying to decrypt?

Comment: All I want to do is xor A2 with A5 and get 07 as string. That's it.

Comment: OK, I've updated the code to work as you describe. Tests out OK

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using a third party library, the following solution works using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
MutableList<String> decryptedPasswordInPairs = Lists.mutable.with("A2")
    .collectWith((oddPair, A5) ->
            CharAdapter.adapt(oddPair)
                .injectIntoWithIndex(
                    ByteLists.mutable.empty(),
                    (bytes, character, index) ->
                        bytes.with((byte) (character ^ A5.charAt(index % A5.length()))))
                .makeString(""), "A5");
decryptedPasswordInPairs.each(System.out::println);
```

I used the following imports:

```
import org.eclipse.collections.api.list.MutableList;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.factory.Lists;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.factory.primitive.ByteLists;
import org.eclipse.collections.impl.string.immutable.CharAdapter;
```

By using the primitive [`ByteList`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/ByteList.html) available in Eclipse Collections, I was able to avoid boxing.  The method `makeString` which is available on `ByteList` allows you to control the separator.  Passing in an empty `String` gets rid of the comma that you get using `toString` on a `List`.  The class [`CharAdapter`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.1.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/string/immutable/CharAdapter.html) provides a set of `char` based protocols around `String` including the method I used here named `injectIntoWithIndex`.

The code can also be broken into smaller steps to make it slightly less dense and potentially easier to read.

```
MutableList<String> decryptedPasswordInPairs = Lists.mutable.with("A2")
    .collect(CharAdapter::adapt)
    .collectWith((oddPair, A5) ->
        oddPair.injectIntoWithIndex(
            ByteLists.mutable.empty(),
            (bytes, character, index) ->
                bytes.with((byte) (character ^ A5.charAt(index % A5.length())))), "A5")
    .collectWith(ByteList::makeString, "");
decryptedPasswordInPairs.each(System.out::println);
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

> `result` is displayed as `[0,7]` instead of `07`

This is because you are printing the list as a `String`.

You could get rid of that doing something like:

```
for (Byte b : sample) {
    System.out.print(b);
}
```

Or maybe, but not very elegant:

```
String result = sample.toString().replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
decryptedPasswordInPairs.add(result);
```

Comment: Is there a safe solution for line: String result = sample.toString(); ? I mean is there another toString method for this?

Comment: string is defined in the object class and the list implements it like that...  I would use the for loop and some kind of string builder if any is need it :)

Answer (score -1):

Convert your list into array like below. Thanks @ bcsb1001

> T[] toArray(T[] a)
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements
> in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the
> runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array. If
> the list fits in the specified array, it is returned therein.
> Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the
> specified array and the size of this list.

```
Byte[] byteArray = sample.toArray(new Byte[0])
```

after that , You can create String from Byte array.

Use this constructor:

[image]

```
String str= new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert "List<Byte> sample" to byte Array?

Comment: Sorry that did not work. It says cannot resolve constructor. I guess there is not such constructor.

Comment: Since you've linked the documentation: Show us the constructor, which accepts an `Object[]` ...

Comment: `byte[] != Object[]`. Also, with the edit, you can't cast an `Object[]` to `Byte`. It should be `Byte[] byteArray = sample.toArray(new Byte[0]);`

Comment: @bcsb1001 one should prefer `sample.toArray(new Byte[sample.size()])` to avoid creating two arrays, instead of one.

Comment: Still it did not work. I guess there is a difference between Byte [] and byte[].

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944377/how-to-convert-byte-to-byte-and-the-other-way-around

Comment: This is definitely wrong. It can't work like that because `Byte[] != Byte[]`. The String class has no constructor that accepts `byte[]`. And since autoboxing of arrays is not possible, this answer is wrong.